# Order of variables in chi square test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, inference, chi-squared-test, terminology

Minor question, but I am wondering if there is a convention in how we say the order of variables in a chi square test for association between 2 categorical variables, say X and Y. In regression, for example, the order of the variables in the phrase "regress Y on X" indicates which is the response and which is the explanatory variable. Similarly, *if* we had a case where we thought of one categorical var (say X) as potentially causing an effect in the other categorical var (i.e. Y), would we choose to say "*we are testing for an association between X and Y*" rather than "*we are testing for an association between Y and X*"?

I know technically the order doesn't matter (both as far as the test is concerned and also in the conjunction used in the phrase itself) and of course if you simply call it the "chi-square test for independence" the issue is moot, but I was just wondering.

Comment: It seems like you already answered the question. There's certainly no need to specify any kind of predictor/response (IV/DV) relationship for a test that considers only dependence vs independence, but there's also nothing stopping you from phrasing it as if they were IV and DV. What's done in practice would depend on situation, individual preference and the conventions of the application area or (say) of the journal (if one were involved).

Comment: There is no need, as @Glen_b has said, and I've encountered no convention with regard to this in educational, psychological, or health care research.